# How can I simplify and optimize this C# code

Tags: c#, performance, optimization, foreach

I have a method like this :

```
public ConcurrentBag<FileModel> GetExceptionFiles(List<string> foldersPath, List<string> someList)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < foldersPath.Count; i++)
    {
        var index = i;

        new Thread(delegate()
        {
            foreach (var file in BrowseFiles(foldersPath[index]))
            {
                if (file.Name.Contains(someList[0]) || file.Name.Contains(someList[1]))
                {
                    using (var fileStream = File.Open(file.Path, FileMode.Open))
                    using (var bufferedStream = new BufferedStream(fileStream))
                    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(bufferedStream))
                    ...
```

To give you more details:

This methods starts n threads (= foldersPath.Count) and each thread is going to read all the files which contains the strings listed in `someList`.

Right now my list contains only 2 strings (conditions), this is why im doing  :

```
file.Name.Contains(someList[0]) || file.Name.Contains(someList[1])
```

What I want to do now is to replace this line with something that check all elements in the list `someList`

How can I do that?

`Edit`

Now that I replaced that line by **if (someList.Any(item => file.Name.Contains(item)))**

The next question is how can I optimize the performance of this code, knowing that each item in `foldersPath` is a separate hard drive in my network (which is always not more that 5 hard drives).

Comment: Are you sure these threads actually accelerate the whole process? You should be I/O bound anyway.

Comment: HOLY £$%& you are creating a ton of threads, and not even using the thread pool. First up. YOU SHOULD NOT BE THREADING with a modern computer programming language like C# for something like this (Java, go nuts). Use async await.

Comment: In your question text, you ask for *simplification* of the code, while in your tags, you list *optimization* and *performance*. Those might be contradictory goals to aim for.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski, I think (Yes), because each folder in `foldersPath` is actualy a separte hard drive

Comment: @Aron async/await is good for some cases, in other cases creating threads is far better.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper can you propose something to optimize the code ?

Comment: First thing I'd do is drop the thread creation and switch over to PLinq: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Dirk I actually work in one of those fields where we typically are CPU bound. Fact is 99% of the time beginners don't know what CPU bound means...I find its better to advise beginners to use Single Threaded by default.

Comment: Should this not rather be asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @BerndLinde The actual question is about how to check if a file name contains any of the values in a list of strings, the title however is misleading.

Comment: @Christophe: No, because that would only add contradictory answers. As an example: [Joeb454's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27150083/1430156) makes the code *more* readable ("simpler"), but (due to the frequent invocation of a delegate) possibly *less* performant. I'd like to ask *you* to clarify in your question which one you are actually looking for.

Comment: PS I hate it when people use for loops. USE A FOREACH!

Comment: With the edited question, this should really be asked on codereview.stackexchange.com since there is no more error or problem that you are experiencing, but rather want a review of your code for optimization, which is what that is for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like `if (someList.Any(item => file.Name.Contains(item)))`

This will iterate each item in `someList`, and check if any of the items are contained in the file name, returning a boolean value to indicate whether any matches were found or not

Comment: It should be `Any` instead of `All`.

Comment: Spotted that while I was editing it to add a little more of an explanation. Thanks @Dirk

Answer (score 1):

Fristly.

There is an old saying is computer science, "There are two hard problems in CS, Naming, Cache Invalidation and Off by One Errors."

Don't use `for` loops, unless you absolutely have to, the tiny perf gain you get isn't worth the debug time (assuming there is any perf gain in this version of .net).

Secondly

`new Thread`. Don't do that. The creation of a thread is extremely slow and takes up lots of resources, especially for a short lived process like this. Added to the fact, there is overhead in passing data between threads. Use the `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(WaitCallback)` instead, if you MUST do short lived threads.

However, as I previously alluded to. Threads are an abstraction for CPU resources. I honestly doubt you are CPU bound. Threading is going to cost you more than you think. Stick to single threads. However you ARE I/O bound, therefore make full usage of asynchronous I/O.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<FileModel>> GetExceptionFiles(List<string> foldersPath, List<string> someList)
{
    foreach (var folderPath in foldersPath)        
    foreach (var file in BrowseFiles(folderPath))
    {
         if (false == someList.Any(x => file.Name.Contains(x, StringComparer.InvariantCultureCaseIgnore)))
             continue;
         using (var fileStream = await File.OpenTaskAsync(file.Path, FileMode.Open))
         using (var bufferedStream = new BufferedStream(fileStream))
         using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(bufferedStream))
         ...
             yield return new FileModel();
```